# Bash cut not using stdin

Tags: linux, bash, git-bash, cut, mingw-w64

I'm trying to get the last 4 directories in a file path along with the filename. I'm doing this on a windows machine that has MinGW64. Apparently this doesn't have the "rev" command so I had to do my own:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
reverse=""

len=${#input}
for (( i=$len-1; i>=0; i-- ))
do 
  reverse="$reverse${input:$i:1}"
done

printf "$reverse"
```

This works if I do a simple `~/reverse.sh 'hello world'` Output: `dlrow olleh`

However, if I do this:
    `echo $(~/reverse.sh "/c/Users/myusername/5thfolder/4thfolder/3rdfolder/2ndfolder/1stfolder/this_is_my_target_file.sql") | cut -d"/" -f5-`
My output is this:
`redlofht4/redlofht5/emanresuym/sresU/c/`

I would expect it to reverse the input filename, then pass that output ( `lqs.elif_tegrat_ym_si_siht/redlofts1/redlofdn2/redlofdr3/redlofht4/redlofht5/emanresuym/sresU/c/` ) to cut. Then cut would take the first 5 fields and I would get the output `lqs.elif_tegrat_ym_si_siht/redlofts1/redlofdn2/redlofdr3/redlofht4/`
which I would then be able to reverse again to get the output I need.

Comment: Why do you place the command inside a subshell? `$(...)`. Your script prints to stdout, so you don't need the echo. Remove the echo and the subshell, the output should be piped to your `cut` command.

Comment: Your code seems to be doing the right thing.  Since you are picking up 5th field onwards in the reversed string, you are not going to get the full file name.

Comment: My system has a `rev` command which reverses each line of input. But it's from an "util-linux" package so YMMV.

Comment: For your information, `rev` might be useful here : `echo "123" | rev` outputs `321`

Comment: To all the people who say to use "rev" - that's obviously what I should do. I just can't - it's not on my system (which uses MinGW64 (as I said)). It's right there in the first couple of lines.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `-f-5` instead of `-f5-` in

```
... | cut -d"/" -f-5
```

You can also use `sed` to get the last 4 directories in a file path along with the filename:

```
echo "/fff/eee/ddd/ccc/bbb/aaa/file.sql" | sed -r 's|.*(/.*/.*/.*/.*/.*)$|\1|'
```

will output

```
/ddd/ccc/bbb/aaa/file.sql
```

Comment: If I didn't get it wrong, the OPs question is to reverse the string. You output woudn't reverse the folder names.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with sed so I appreciate this. But my script is trying to be portable and wouldn't your `sed` not work as expected if the folder structure was different? But really my question was "why isn't cut accepting the reversed string?" To ChristophS - earlier - I put it in a subshell because this behaviour has been happening in every way and this is just my latest iteration of trying it.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Ugh. -f-5 instead of -f5 - stupid me!